# UDP vs TCP in cluster communication

Tags: c, network-programming, ipc

I'm working on a software that will be running on HP blades/Linux, each blade will have multiple programs and I'm considering UDP for the IPC communication. The size of messages between the blades/programs won't be bigger than a 400Bytes.

I used to use TCP before and I'm not experienced in using UDP so the question here is this, is using UDP for cluster communication wise based on your experience?

Comment: Is latency a concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your requirements for reliability. As you know UDP provides no delivery guarantees or even ordering guarantees (packets may arrive out-of-order). If your application is tolerant of this, or if you can make it tolerant with relatively simple code, UDP is definitely a better choice - it is lower latency, lower overhead, and programmatically simpler to deal with.

If reliability is an absolute requirement, then unless you're really hard core and trying to squeeze every last ounce of performance out of your cluster, just use TCP. Otherwise you'll simply find yourself trying to reinvent the mechanisms TCP uses to guarantee reliability, and you probably won't do as good a job as TCP does (it's had decades of tweaking and tuning).

Also note that on small LANs, despite the lack of any guarantee, UDP is quite reliable, but even in a perfect setup you still have to expect the occasional dropped packet. The more complex your cluster's network gets and the higher the bandwidth utilization of the system, the less reliable it will be.